# Error: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name

Tags: linux, rhel, iptables, proxy, squid

I am trying to configure proxy server on RHEL Server 6.5 using Squid and iptables. Below is the command I executed and the error message it displayed:

```
vzlptest01 root [root] > iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

Some more details:

```
vzlptest01 root [root] > cat /proc/net/ip_tables_matches
limit
state
length
ttl
tcpmss
multiport
multiport
tos
tos
dscp
icmp
udplite
udp
tcp

vzlptest01 root [root] > cat /proc/net/ip_tables_targets
DNAT
SNAT
LOG
TOS
TOS
DSCP
TCPMSS
REJECT
ERROR
```

**Edit:**

```
vzlptest01 root [root] > iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

How to deal with this issue?

Comment: That command worked for me on my CentOS VM, if you trying to use iptables and squid together, shouldn't you specify nat table instead of the default filter?

Comment: That too won't doesn't work. I am running this command on a Parallels Virtuozzo Container.

Comment: I don't know if parallels uses a custom kernel, but on a stock CentOS kernel you need to load the kernel module `nf_conntrack`  to have the `-m state` target available. check with `lsmod`.  Alternatively your primary network interface may not be called `eth0` but could be something like `vnet0`

Comment: Any other iptables commands function as expected?

Comment: post the output of `iptables -S`

Comment: @SamiLaine - `iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT`, `iptables -A INPUT -s 172.22.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: @Creek - Edited in the question itself.